# $\frac {dc}{dx} = b + b_1 x - a c$. Find $ c $ as a function of $ x $ if $ c=0 $ when $ x=0 $

Tags: integration, economics

Manufacturing and marketing costs $ c $ are related to the number of items $ x $ by the relation:-

$\frac {dc}{dx} = b + b_1 x - a c$
($a , b_1 , b$ are constants)

Find $ c $ as a function of $ x $ if $ c = 0 $ when $ x = 0 $.

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! It is a separable differential equation. Start solving it for $c$ and apply the condition. But, please show your work !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: don't you mean linear ?

Comment: Moreover, as @Yves Daoust commented, it is just linear.

Comment: and you want to go to the moon...

Comment: Thanks @Claude Leibovici.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that

$$\frac{d}{dx}c(x)+ac(x)=e^{-ax}\frac{d}{dx}(c(x)e^{ax})$$ so that

$$\frac{d}{dx}(c(x)e^{ax})=(b+b_1x)e^{ax}$$
and
$$c(x)e^{ax}-c(0)=\int_0^x(b+b_1z)e^{az}dz.$$

The integral can be evaluated by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation to @Yves Daoust answer

$$c(x)e^{ax} = \frac {be^{ax} + b_1e^{ax}(x-1)}{a} + k$$
$$c(x) = \frac {b + b_1x - b_1}{a} + k $$